# How many ways are there to distribute 0 and 1 in a vector of length $N$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

EDIT: How many ways are there to distribute $0$ and $1$ in a vector of length $N$ such that  the number of zeros and 1 is the same (Suppose $N$ is even). I'm guessing it's $\binom{N}{2}$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It would just be $2^N$, you have two choices for every entry.

Comment: @ZainPatel, I edited my question.

Comment: You have to choose $N/2$ places where to put your ones, and the other will be zero. Hence the answer is $\binom{N}{N/2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $N/2$ zeroes and $N/2$ ones. It suffices to choose the position of all of the zeroes, so we are choosing $N/2$ slots out of $N$ possibilities:

$$\binom{N}{N/2} = \frac{N!}{\left((N/2)!\right)^2}$$

This is a [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @Enthusiastic should be updated now

Answer (score 2):

After your edit (Zubins answer - before his edit - was correct before your edit).

You have to select the $\frac{N}{2}$ places that should be $1$ (or $0$) and then the rest will just have to be $0$ (or $1$), you can do that in:
$$
\binom{N}{N/2}
$$
ways.